# Program making blank output file, C

Tags: c, arrays, for-loop

I have a small program which reverses the words when inputted however for some reason the first input is being outputted as a blank without allowing the user to enter any input for it. This is happening for any amount of n, and I have been playing around with the for loops (were I think the error is) however I have not yet managed to eliminate the problem.

Thanks In Advance and Happy Holidays!

**CODE:**

```
int main()
{
    int n;

    printf("How many strings would you like to insert?\n");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    n=n+1;
    char s[n][100];


    printf("Insert %d strings\n", n-1);

    for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        gets(s[i]);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i <n ; i++) {
        reverseWords(s[i]);
        printf("The number %d Sentence is %s\n", i+1, s[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Input/Output:**

```
How many strings would you like to insert?
3

Insert 3 strings
hello whats up
bye dude

The number 1 Sentence is
The number 2 Sentence is up whats hello
The number 3 Sentence is dude bye

Process finished with exit code 0
```

**EDIT:**

I managed to find a fix myself. Thoughts on this fix?

```
int main()
{
    int n;

    printf("How many strings would you like to insert?\n");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    char s[n][100];

    printf("Insert %d strings\n", n);

    for(int i=0; i<n+1; i++) {
        gets(s[i]);
    }

    for (int i = 1; i <n+1 ; i++) {
        reverseWords(s[i]);
        printf("The number %d sentence in reverse is %s\n", i, s[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**New Output:**
"G:\UoM\Second Year\Programming Principles in C\Question 1\cmake-build-debug\CLion.exe"
How many strings would you like to insert?
3

```
Insert 3 strings
Hello Carl whats up?
Dude Whats giong on?
wow nice!

The number 1 sentence is up? whats Carl Hello
The number 2 sentence is on? giong Whats Dude
The number 3 sentence is nice! wow
```

Comment: First of all, never ***ever*** use `gets`. [It's a dangerous function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used), and has therefore been removed from the C specification. Use e.g. [`fgets`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) instead.

Comment: As for your problem, there are probably quite a few duplicates here on stackoverflow.com, but in short the problem is the `Enter` key you press for the input of the number. It's added to the input buffer as a newline, a newline that the `scanf` *doesn't* remove.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to modify your for loop as below. It will help you to get the expected output

```
for (int i = 1; i <n ; i++) 
{
  reverseWords(s[i]);
  printf("The number %d Sentence  %s\n", i, s[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all [don't use gets()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used). Instead, use [fgets()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets).

The problem is occurring because of the newline character remains on the input stream. When you give number of strings input, you enter number and hit the `ENTER` key. So, the input stream has `3\n` in it *[`3` is number of strings input]*. The `scanf()` will read the `3`, but not the newline following it. That newline character will remain on the input stream. As soon as the `gets()` called, it read that newline character. The `gets()` reads until a newline character or the end-of-file is reached and if newline character found, it read but does not copy it to buffer and appends a terminating null character to the buffer. Hence, you are getting the first string as empty string.

A quick fix of your problem is to call `getchar()` immediately after the `scanf()` which will consume the stray newline character. But this is also not the perfect solution. You should not mix up the `scanf()` and `gets()` or other input functions. May you can consider using `fgets()` consistently in your program. For number of strings input you can use `strtol()` or `sscanf()` to convert the string to number.

NOTE: If you use `fgets()`, remember that it consider newline character as a valid character and include it in the string copied to buffer passed. Make sure to remove trailing newline character. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693776/removing-trailing-newline-character-from-fgets-input).